# Importing a list from excel, but having trouble splitting it into 4 columns

Tags: excel, python-2.7, user-interface

I know this is very basic, but I have been using Python for 2 weeks now and banging my head against the wall trying to fix this. I have checked almost every single thread in here and tried to make sense of the Python 2.7 documentation and also researched whatever excerpts from Programming with Win32 by Hammod I could find.
Below is a section of my code. I am pulling in a named range from excel into a Python Gui. The data comes into row=4, column=1 as I coded it. The problem is I need to parse this named range so that the range (which is four float points)  is split amongst row=4 clomuns 1,2,3,4. I know this is basic. I wouldnt have posted if I could find the answer anywhere else. If someone could just point me in the right direction i would really appreciate it.

```
    xl = win32com.client.Dispatch('excel.application')
    wbs = xl.Workbooks
    wb = wbs.Open('C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\AutoPrime.xls')
    xl.visible = 1
    xlSheet = xl.Sheets(1)
    xlSheet.Range('Fronts').Value

    #Frame
    Ftreas = Frame(F, relief="groove", border=2)
    Ftreas.pack(side="left")
    lp2a = Label(Ftreas, text=xl.ActiveSheet.Range('Fronts').Value, justify='center')
    lp2a.grid(row=4,column=1,  sticky='EW')
```

Answer (score 0):

While I have not worked with Phyton before, I know that your line `xlSheet.Range('Fronts')` will return a Range object. You can access individual cells of a Range object with the default property, e.g.:

```
rng = xlSheet.Range('Fronts')
val1 = rng(1, 1).Value
val2 = rng(2, 1).Value //this returns the cell in row 2/column 1 of the range
arr = rng.Cells //this will return a 4x1 array of values
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I'd there a way to incorporate this into a loop so that I don't have to pull each cell individually. Ideally, I want to create a for loop that takes the data, feeds it across 4 columns. Then takes the next 4 bits and feeds it to the row below. I'm going to need to do this for several frames so I was thinking of creating a class. Does this make sense?

Comment: You're welcome. Sure you can do a loop instead of addressing each cell (that was just to better show the properties of the object). I wouldn't go for an extra class here, but rather just have 2 nested loops - the first one going from row/frame to the next and the second one going by the 4 columns...

Comment: I added your code and I get an error" val1 = rng.Cells(1, 1).Value
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'Cells'" I noticed you mentioned PHP in your comments. I'm using Python ( I accidentally tagged PHP, apologies) I am trying my best to use that last line. I thinmk thats exactly what i need,..

Comment: @JohnGorman: Sorry, I somehow misread your question and added the PHP tag instead of the Pyton tag - my bad! I see you already changed it!

Regarding your error: Not really sure, I can help you much further, as I have no Python experience - I only know the Excel object model. Try removing the `.Cells` in the code (I updated the answer accordingly) - the default behavior of the Range object should also do the job. However, not sure with Python, sorry! :-(